# using different condition based on column value possible by switch case

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a query and i want different conditions to be used as per value in a column.

```
SELECT *
FROM com140 cm
WHERE cm.csnstar IN (90)
```

but the problem comes because i want this to happen.

when `cm.csnrsncde IN (135,177)`   i want this condition to execute

```
AND cm.duedate > (SELECT MAX(e.dte1) 
                         FROM events e 
                         WHERE e.ispec   ='FI560'
                         AND   e.inrtyp  ='RVP'
                         AND   e.trntyp1 = 'RP'
                         AND   e.staevt  = 55 
                         AND   e.dte2  > DATE_1)
```

but when `cm.csnrsncde IN (91,98,172)` i want only below condition to execute not the previous one.

```
AND cm.duedate> DATE1
```

Please help me. 
Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that you added should work

```
SELECT *
FROM   com140 cm
WHERE  cm.csnstar = 90
AND   ((cm.csnrsncde IN ( 135, 177 )
    AND cm.duedate > (SELECT Max(e.dte1)
                       FROM   events e
                       WHERE  e.ispec = 'FI560'
                       AND e.inrtyp = 'RVP'
                       AND e.trntyp1 = 'RP'
                       AND e.staevt = 55
                       AND e.dte2 > DATE_1) )
    OR (cm.csnrsncde IN (91,98,172)
         AND cm.duedate > DATE1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `Where` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   com140 cm
WHERE  cm.csnstar = 90
        OR ( cm.csnrsncde IN ( 135, 177 )
             AND cm.duedate > (SELECT Max(e.dte1)
                               FROM   events e
                               WHERE  e.ispec = 'FI560'
                                      AND e.inrtyp = 'RVP'
                                      AND e.trntyp1 = 'RP'
                                      AND e.staevt = 55
                                      AND e.dte2 > DATE_1) )
        OR ( cm.csnrsncde IN ( 91, 98, 172 )
             AND cm.duedate > DATE1 )
```

Comment: both are in OR condition, after cm.csnstar = 90 , does it means that even if the condition cm.csnstar = 90 satisfies the query returns ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this okay ?

```
SELECT *
FROM   com140 cm
WHERE  cm.csnstar = 90
AND   ((cm.csnrsncde IN ( 135, 177 )
        AND cm.duedate > (SELECT Max(e.dte1)
                           FROM   events e
                           WHERE  e.ispec = 'FI560'
                           AND e.inrtyp = 'RVP'
                           AND e.trntyp1 = 'RP'
                           AND e.staevt = 55
                           AND e.dte2 > DATE_1) )
        OR (cm.csnrsncde IN (91,98,172)
             AND cm.duedate > DATE1))
```

Comment: You will never get results

Comment: @VR46 Hi, Can you please let me know why i will never get the result? whats wrong in that ?